# Automorphic group of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n.$ Then $Aut(G)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Why is this true?

Comment: Hint: consider maps of the form $a\mapsto a^k$.

Comment: You can find many answers if you write this to Google uncle.

Comment: That's true, but I prefer hints over full answers.

Comment: Then you have certainly come to the right place.

Comment: @S.Sheng: Good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $f:G\to G$ by $f(a)=a^k$ is an isomorphism if and only if $(k,n)=1$ where $G$ is a cylic group of order $n$.

First try to show above lemma after that try to show the converse i.e any isomorphism correspond to a such $f$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 2):

let $a$ be a generator for $G$. any automorphism $\gamma$ must map $a$ to $a^g$ where $g$ is  relatively prime to $n$ (an automorphism must preserve orders of elements). the rest follows

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First use the face that $\varphi:\, a\mapsto a^{k}$ is an automorphism
of a **cyclic group** iff $(k,n)=1$.

Then, for a general group $G$, 
$$
\varphi(\langle x\rangle)=\langle x\rangle\iff(k,n)=1
$$

and note that 
$$
G=\cup_{x\in G}\langle x\rangle
$$